# Sorting based on all heighest number

Tags: java, sorting

I want to get the person having highest values from all the tables. Below is the example which i retrieve from db

```
Id  play(count) listen(count) display(count) comment(count)
a   3           1             4              2
b   2           5             3              7
c   6           3             0              1
d   0           0             5              4
e   6           4             8              9
f   4           2             5              7
```

in this all counts related to same id but coming from different tables.Here I want **e(6,4,8,9)** as sorting output. How can i do this sorting?

Comment: Do you want to process the resultset using Java or optimize the SQL query to fetch sorted result?

Comment: i want to process result in java.

Comment: Show us your pojo class.

Comment: i have not create any POJO right now as i am not clear how to do it. I am executing the queries and directly getting their out put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // Assuming that you are working with query output resultset
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
            li.add(rs.getInt("PLAY"));
            li.add(rs.getInt("LISTEN"));
            li.add(rs.getInt("DISPLAY"));
            li.add(rs.getInt("COMMENT"));

            map.put(rs.getString("ID"), li);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        /* SQLException handler */
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }

    map = sortByValues(map);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue());
    }

}

public static Map<String, List<Integer>> sortByValues(Map<String, List<Integer>> map) {

    List<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>> list = 
        new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>>()        {        

        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> m1, Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> m2) {

            int sum1 = 0;
            for(Integer d : m1.getValue())
                sum1 += d;

            int sum2 = 0;
            for(Integer d : m2.getValue())
                sum2 += d;

            return (new Integer(sum2)).compareTo(new Integer(sum1));
        } 
    }) ;

    Map<String, List<Integer>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry: list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return result;
}
```

> Note: I have a separate method `sortByValues()` to do the comparison. This makes code neat to read and reusable rather than implementing an anonymous block after `try-catch`.

**What's happening here?**
Our aim is to sort IDs by different values fetched from Database. I feel `Map` data structure to be the apt one here. Example Map which is represented in a generic way as `Map<String, List<Integers>>`.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Creates the linked hash map to store the  pair

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
```

Creates an `Arraylist` object inside `while` loop to store each value fetched from database. It's scope dies within this loop.

```
map.put(id, li);
```

Adds each users id and values in the format `Map<String, List<Integer>>`

```
map = sortByValues(map);
```

Accesses the static `sortByValues()` to fetch the sorted map based on values it has.

```
sortByValues(Map<String, List<Integer>> map)
```

Overrides the `Comparator`'s `compare()` anonymously and performs sorting based upon values. It sums up each ID's value and does the comparison.

**Mock Execution:**

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        // Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
        li.add(1);
        li.add(2); 
        li.add(3);
        // MathUtils.sum()
        map.put("a", li);
        // map.put("a", 5);

        List<Integer> li2 = new ArrayList<>();
        li2.add(3);
        li2.add(-1); 
        li2.add(1);
        map.put("b", li2);


        List<Integer> li3 = new ArrayList<>();
        li3.add(10);
        li3.add(-1); 
        li3.add(9);
        map.put("c", li3);

        map = sortByValues(map);

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue());
        }
```

Result:

```
c,[10, -1, 9]
a,[1, 2, 3]
b,[3, -1, 1]
```